# BindingList and Nested Properties

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, nested, bindinglist

I have class a that keeps track of video streams, and for simplicity I group like properties in a sub classes using auto properties to access them.  I then bound the whole class to an BindingList, but only the None Nested Properties show up.  How can i get the Nested Properties to show up also?

```
public class Stream: : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
public bool InUse {
    get { return _inUse; }
    set {
        _inUse = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("InUse");
        }
    }
}
....
internal SubCodec Codec { get; set; }
internal class SubCodec
{
    public string VideoCodec 
    {
        get { return _audioCodec; }
        set {
            _audioCodec = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AudioCodec");
        }
    }
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fire `OnPropertyChanged` of the parent type, not on the child type.

```
public class Stream : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SubCodec _codec;
    internal SubCodec Codec
    {
        get
        {
            return _codec;
        }
        set
        {
            _codec = value;
            //note that you'll have problems if this code is set to other parents, 
            //or is removed from this object and then modified
            _codec.Parent = this;
        }
    }
    internal class SubCodec
    {
        internal Stream Parent { get; set; }

        private string _audioCodec;
        public string VideoCodec
        {
            get { return _audioCodec; }
            set
            {
                _audioCodec = value;
                Parent.OnPropertyChanged("VideoCodec");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It may be simpler to put the `Stream` in the constructor of `SubCodec` and not allow it to be changed.  It would be one way of avoiding the problems I mention in the comment of the `Codec` set method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise `PropertyChanged` event on `SubCodec`

```
private SubCoded _codec;
internal SubCodec Codec 
{
      get {return _codec;}  
      set 
      {
            _codec = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Codec");
       }
 }
```